# LoadLibrary from offset in a file

Tags: windows, dll, loadlibrary

I am writing a scriptable game engine, for which I have a large number of classes that perform various tasks. The size of the engine is growing rapidly, and so I thought of splitting the large executable up into dll modules so that only the components that the game writer actually uses can be included. When the user compiles their game (which is to say their script), I want the correct dll's to be part of the final executable. I already have quite a bit of overlay data, so I figured I might be able to store the dll's as part of this block. My question boils down to this:

Is it possible to trick LoadLibrary to start reading the file at a certain offset? That would save me from having to either extract the dll into a temporary file which is not clean, or alternatively scrapping the automatic inclusion of dll's altogether and simply instructing my users to package the dll's along with their games.

Initially I thought of going for the "load dll from memory" approach but rejected it on grounds of portability and simply because it seems like such a horrible hack.

Any thoughts?

Kind regards,

Philip Bennefall

Comment: You seem to be describing a very convoluted reinvention of static linking.  That's what static linking is all about - including the necessary parts of library code in the executable.

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what I want to do but it has to be done based on the script content. Thus, I cannot precompile it as that would lead me back to where I am at present. When a user "compiles" their game, it is not an actual C++ compilation that takes place; it is merely the script engine that compiles its own rather high level byte code. This byte code is then encrypted and appended to a copy of the engine executable, which checks to see if it has the appropriate overlay data appended to it when it begins executing.

Comment: Sounds like you need a tool to figure out what parts of the engine are and aren't used, and then to re-link the engine executable suitably, either using an actual linker or your own tool for reprocessing the file.

Comment: Can you recommend any such tools?

Comment: Sorry, it's not something I've needed to research for the windows platform recently.  Probably your first decision will be between having the developer re-link the engine, or coming up with something to strip un-needed parts out of an already linked executable you supply.

Comment: That is a thought, but it seems almost as risky as loading the dll manually from a raw memory buffer. I'll have to look further into it.

Comment: Risk of what?  I would think packaging time "tricks" are safer than runtime ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.  Loading a DLL doesn't actually require any physical memory.  Windows creates a memory mapped file for the DLL content.  Code from the DLL only ever gets loaded when your program calls that code.  Unused code doesn't require any system resources beyond reserved memory pages.  You have 2 billion bytes worth of that on a 32-bit operating system.  You have to write a *lot* of code to consume them all, 50 megabytes of machine code is already a very large program.

The memory mapping is also the reason you cannot make LoadLibrary() do what you want to do.  There is no realistic scenario where you need to.

Look into the linker's /DELAYLOAD option to improve startup performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think every solution for that task is "horrible hack" and nothing more.

Simplest way that I see is create your own virtual drive that present custom filesystem and hacks system access path from one real file (compilation of your libraries) to multiple separate DLL-s. For example like [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) does (it's open-source). And than you may use `LoadLibrary` function without changes.

But only right way I see is change your task and don't use this approach. I think you need to create your own script interpreter and compiler, using structures, pointers and so on.

**The main thing is that I don't understand your benefit from use of libraries**. I think any compiled code in current time does not weigh so much and may be packed very good. Any other resources may be loaded dynamically at first call. All you need to do is to organize the working cycles of all components of the script engine in right way.